# How to define an input for python multiprocessing function to take all the files in a directory?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

This question may sounds basic because I do not know that much about multiprocessing, I am just learning.

I have python code which processes a bunch of files in a directory.

```
with Pool(processes=cores) as pp:  
        pp.map(function, list)
```

Here is my code:

```
path = '/data/personal'
print("Running with PID: %d" % getpid())



    psl = PublicSuffixList()
    d = defaultdict(set)
    start = time()

#
     files_list = glob(path)
     for filename in files:
        print(filename)
        f = open(filename, 'r')
        for n, line in enumerate(f):
            line = line[:-1]
            ip,reversed_domain_1= line.split('|')
            reversed_domain_2 = reversed_domain_1.split('.')
            reversed_domain_3 = list(reversed(reversed_domain_2))
            domain = ('.'.join(reversed_domain_3))
            domain = psl.get_public_suffix(domain)
            d[ip].add(domain)

###
    for ip, domains in d.iteritems():
        for domain in domains:
            print(ip,domain)
```

How can I convert it to be done in a multiprocessing pool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can process each file in a separate process like this:

```
from os import getpid
from collections import defaultdict
from glob import glob
from multiprocessing import Pool
from time import time
from functools import partial

path = '/data/personal'
print("Running with PID: %d" % getpid())


def process_file(psl, filename):
    print(filename)
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    for n, line in enumerate(f):
        line = line[:-1]
        ip,reversed_domain_1= line.split('|')
        reversed_domain_2 = reversed_domain_1.split('.')
        reversed_domain_3 = list(reversed(reversed_domain_2))
        domain = ('.'.join(reversed_domain_3))
        domain = psl.get_public_suffix(domain)
        return ip, domain

if __name__ == "__main__":
    psl = PublicSuffixList()
    d = defaultdict(set)
    start = time()
    files_list = glob(path)
    pp = Pool(processes=cores)
    func = partial(process_file, psl)
    results = pp.imap_unordered(func, files_list)
    for ip, domain in results:
       d[ip].add(domain)
    p.close()
    p.join()

    for ip, domains in d.iteritems():
        for domain in domains:
            print(ip,domain)
```

Note that the `defaultdict` is populated in the parent process, because you can't actually share the same `defaultdict` between multiple processes without using a `multiprocessing.Manager`. You could do that here if you wanted, but I don't think its necessary. Instead, as soon as any child has a result available, we add it to the `defaultdict` in the parent. Using `imap_unordered` instead of `map` enables us to receive results on-demand, rather than having to wait for all of them to be ready. The only other notable thing is the use of `partial` to enable passing the `psl` list to all the child processes in addition to an item from `files_list` with `imap_unordered`.

One important note here: Using `multiprocessing` for this kind of operation may not actually improve performance. A lot of the work you're doing here is reading from disk, which can't be sped up via multiple processes; your hard drive can only do one read operation at a time. Getting read requests for different files from a bunch of processes at once can actually slow things down that doing them sequentially, because it potentially has to to constantly switch to different areas of the physical disk to read a new line from each file. Now, it's possible that the CPU-bound work you're doing with each line is expensive enough to dominate that I/O time, in which case you will see a speed boost.

Comment: Thanks @dano for your very complete answer. I agree with you that it might be more time consuming but I wanted to give it a shot. When I am running your code I get this error? do you know why?                                      with Pool(processes=cores) as pp:
AttributeError: 'Pool' object has no attribute '__exit__'

Comment: I am using python 2.7

Comment: @user2058811 Ah, sorry. You can't use `Pool` as a context manager in Python 2.7, it's a 3.x feature. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @user2058811 I found and fixed a typo in my answer, but I have no idea why/how you're seeing that particular error. Are you running the exact code I provided? Can you provide the full traceback?

Comment: @user2058811 We're passing `files_list` to `pool.imap_unordered`, which is basically doing this: `for filename in files_list: process_file(psl, filename)`.

Comment: I changed your code a bit to get it run : The function (process file) only have one input (filename) and it is not returning anything instead I am adding ip and domains to the dictionary within the function. In addition I am also not using the partial command. instead I put psl into the function(process_file) . Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @user2058811 Hmm, that isn't going to work right. The changes you make to the dict in the worker function won't be reflected in the parent process, because each process gets a separate copy of the dict.

Comment: that is fine because I am printing a dic for each file right?

Comment: @user2058811 Ah, if each dict is supposed to be different for each file, then that is fine. I misunderstood what you were trying to do, sorry!